# Sending a message to a Telegram (ASP.net)

Tags: asp.net, telegram-bot

This is the url that i have referred in order to send a message to telegram.
[text](https://medium.com/javarevisited/sending-a-message-to-a-telegram-channel-the-easy-way-eb0a0b32968)

Meanwhile, i have got the api key from BotFather.

This is the returned error when I executed my code.
**The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.**

```
    Private Function send() As Boolean

        Try

            Dim urlString As String = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/sendMessage?chat_id={1}&text={2}"

            Dim apiToken As String = "6046412323:AAGb2bP3SGzeOBK_c7nH6nT5ubS6rjBEzi9"
            Dim chatId As String = "109780439"
            Dim text As String = "Hello world!"
            urlString = String.Format(urlString, apiToken, chatId, text)
            Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(urlString)
            Dim rs As Stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
            Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(rs)
            Dim line As String = ""
            Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

            While line IsNot Nothing
                line = reader.ReadLine()
                If line IsNot Nothing Then sb.Append(line)
            End While

            Dim responseString As String = sb.ToString()

            Response.Write(sb.ToString())

        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Function
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think you need the minus (ie. "-") symbol preceding your Chat ID value (eg. -109780439).  I'll stand corrected, however, if that's not the case